# Background Fetch on iOs with Azure SDK

Tags: ios, azure, xcode5, azure-mobile-services

I have implemented performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

 NSLog(@"1 performFetchWithCompletionHandler");

 MSTable *myTable;

 myTable = [self.authService.client tableWithName:@"TestTable"];

 [myTable readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error in readTable %@",error);
     } else
     {
         NSLog(@"Records: %@",items);
     }
 }];


 NSLog(@"2 performFetchWithCompletionHandler");

 //Tell the system that you ar done.
 completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

}

The output are:

2014-05-23 11:11:10.228 iTest[3096:60b] 1 performFetchWithCompletionHandler
2014-05-23 11:11:10.229 iTest[3096:60b] 2 performFetchWithCompletionHandler

**The Windows Azure Calls are not executed?**

On didReceiveRemoteNotification the problem are the same.

Someone knows the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadWithCompletion is an asynchronous call which means that your code will continue to execute and the block you pass in to readWithCompletion (where you're checking for an error) won't be executed until you actually receive a response from your Mobile Service.  That is why you're seeing the log 1 statement immediately followed by log 2.  You should move your call to completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData) to INSIDE the block you pass to readWithCompletion so it will be called after you get your actual response back from your Mobile Service.

From comments, we discovered that this was working fine in the foreground but not when the app was backgrounded.  When the app is backgrounded and this is called, execution is terminated as soon as you call completionHandler(...).  So even though the call was being made to the Mobile Service, completionHandler(...) was killing it.  The solution was to move completionHandler(...) inside of the callback for the Mobile Services call.

Comment: Hi Chris. That is correct. However, the problem is different. ReadWithCompletion is not executed. This is only a little demo. No azure sdk command are executed. Thanks, peter.

Comment: So no network request is being made?  Can you check by putting a log statement in your script / running Charles to see the network traffic / make sure the device is connected to the internet?

Comment: Hi Chris. The log statement are not executed. The function works fine on running app. The function not executes the azure call with the app in background and fetch request. Thanks, Peter

Comment: Can you check using Charles (or another proxy) to make sure the network request is going through?  Are you building off of the quickstart application or did you drop the Mobile Services framework into a new app?  Is your app successfully interacting with your Mobile Service anywhere else?

Comment: Hi Chris. If my app is not running in the background, everything works perfectly.

Comment: If it's not working when your app is in the background, my guess is that something isn't configured correctly in the app.  Have you done all of the necessary steps to allow background fetching (i.e. set UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum, ensure your request will take less than 30 seconds, etc)?

Comment: Also, if you call completionHandler at the bottom of the method, your app will probably be put back to sleep.  MAKE SURE the call to completionHandler is INSIDE your readWithCompletion block (at the end of it)

Comment: Hi Chris. YES, this ist the solution. Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Awesome.  Updated the answer to reflect that.